# How to get the top 10 highest red/blue value pixels from a bitmap?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

Could anybody point me in the right direction, I need to collect a list of points containing the top 10 red and blue pixels from a bitmap, specifically the top 10 highest red value pixels and top 10 highest blue value pixels.. odd problem i know, but i cannot find anything googling where somebody has attempted the same problem.

At this point i could only imagine conjuring up something terribly slow, hence i'm here first.

**Update:**
I'm not sure how to make the question clearer, by highest i literally mean the highest R byte values and highest B byte values.

```
public unsafe List<Point> GetHighestRedAndBluePixels(Bitmap b)
{
    List<Point> highestRedAndBlues = new List<Point>();
    List<Point> highest10Reds = new List<Point>();
    List<Point> highest10Blues = new List<Point>();

    BitmapData bData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, b.PixelFormat);

    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    byte* scan0 = (byte*)bData.Scan0.ToPointer();

    for(int y = 0; y < bData.Height; ++y)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < bData.Width; ++x)
        {
            byte* data = scan0 + y * bData.Stride + x * bitsPerPixel / 8;
            // looping pixel data fast > need to store highest 10 'R's and 'B's
        }
    }
    b.UnlockBits(bData);

    highestRedAndBlues.AddRange(highest10Reds);
    highestRedAndBlues.AddRange(highest10Blues);
    return highestRedAndBlues;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define highest

Comment: To give directions we need to know both where you are now and where you're trying to go. You've told us neither.

Comment: But what about white pixels? Would (255,0,0) be greater than (255,255,255)? - out of scope, I know, but I am curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way, kind of brute force:

```
private struct MyPixel
{
    public Point Coord { get; set; }
    public Color Rgb { get; set; }
    public float Rfraction
    {
        get { return Rgb.R / (float)(Rgb.R + Rgb.G + Rgb.B); }
    }
    public float Bfraction
    {
        get { return Rgb.B / (float)(Rgb.R + Rgb.G + Rgb.B); }
    }
}
```

and you can use this struct like this:

```
using (Bitmap img = new Bitmap("truc.bmp"))
{
    for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
        {
            var m  = new MyPixel();
            m.Coord = new Point(x, y);
            m.Rgb = img.GetPixel(x,y);
            MyPixels.Add(m);
        }
    }

    var maxreds = MyPixels.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rfraction).Take(10);
    var maxblues = MyPixels.OrderByDescending(x => x.Bfraction).Take(10);
}
```

You can get either the highest red/blue values, or the highest red/blue fractions (cf my comment under your question...)

**EDIT:** A quicker (and still dirty) way to do it, with a BitmapData. Can be heavy in memory (more than 500Mo for a 4032x3024 picture, but 2 seconds to get it done). Heavily based on [BitmapData Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).

```
List<MyPixel> pixels = new List<MyPixel>();
using (Bitmap img = new Bitmap("t.bmp"))
{
    var bmpData = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmpData.Height;
    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
    img.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    for (int i = 0; i < rgbValues.Length; i += 3)
    {
        int x = i / Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
        int y = (i - x * Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride)) / 3;
        var m = new MyPixel();    
        m.Coord = new Point(x, y);
        m.Rgb = Color.FromArgb(rgbValues[i + 2], rgbValues[i + 1], rgbValues[i]);
        pixels.Add(m);
    }

    var maxred = pixels.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rfraction).Take(10);
    var maxblue = pixels.OrderByDescending(x => x.Bfraction).Take(10);
}
```

Comment: Well, this certainly works.. the problem now is that even when locking and accessing the pixel data directly, this method is really slow on a test 900x400 image. I will mark it as the answer, since I've confirmed it actually works, although I will have to try and find a faster way sadly.

Comment: You don't need to mark it as the answer if you don't like it, I won't be offended! As I said, this is brute force, but the idea was to sue a struct (or a class), and a bit of linq to get your values. There are of course much more efficient ways to get rgb values from a bitmap